# Collapse functionality in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am creating collapsable pageblocks in visualforce and im new to visualforce i tried implementing the following code but its not working and throwing error in jquery file like **Refference error $header not defined.** my code is

```
   <apex:page >
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse}"/>
     <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse1}"/>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse2}"/>
   <apex:form >
   <html>
   <head>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(function(){

   $(".header").click(function () {    
   alert("Loopafe");
    $header = $(this);   

    $content = j$header.next();    
    $content.slideToggle(100, function () {       
             $header.text(function () {           
             return $content.is(":visible") ? $(this).attr("src", "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/1404298250000/Minus") : $(this).attr("src", "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/1404298250000/plusimg");
        }); 
    });    
}); 
}); 
</script>
  <style> 
    .container .content {
  display: none;
 padding : 5px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="10" collapsible="True" >           
    <div class="container">
            <img src="https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/1404298250000/plusimg" class="header" />
            <div class="content">
             <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockSection columns="5"  >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Collapse"  id="theSecond1"/>
            <apex:inputText /> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>               
   </apex:pageBlock>

   </div>
 </div>
            <apex:outputText value="First" id="theFirst"/>
            <apex:InputText />

        </apex:pageBlockSection>    
 </apex:pageBlock>
 <body>


</body>
</html>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The div region is visible on page load itself .Can anyone guide me in this

Answer (score 0):

try this sample example

```
<apex:page tabStyle="Account" id="myPage">

 <script language="javascript">
/**
<!-- Collapse PageBlockSection on Page Load-->
**/

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

function dotest() {

 if(document.getElementById('myPage:myForm:myBlock:mySection') != null){
     twistSection(document.getElementById('myPage:myForm:myBlock:mySection').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
 }
}

addLoadEvent(dotest);

</script>

 <apex:form id="myForm">

 <apex:pageBlock id="myBlock">

 <apex:pageBlockSection title="CollapsablePageBlockSection" collapsible="true" id="mySection">

Your Page Block Section Content

 </apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:form >

</apex:page>
```